# nodejs фильтр массива по ключам из другого массива

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Друзья привет , я совсем нуб в ноде и яваскрипт , подскажите я отправляю на экспресс два параметра , делаю запрос в бд мне по этим параметрам дается список ид пользователей у которых есть эти параметры

```
app.get('/productlist/:category&:lang', (request, response) => {
    const category = request.params.category;
    const lang = request.params.lang;
    pool.query('SELECT user_id FROM app_user_category  WHERE category = ? AND lang = ?   ', [category,lang] , (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        response.send(result);
    });
//ответ :
```

[{"user_id":160},{"user_id":240}]

теперь мне надо из другой таблицы выдать профили пользователей по их ид

```
pool.query('SELECT user_id,user_name,user_profile_img FROM tbl_users ', (error, result) => {
        if (error) throw error;
 response.send(result);

    });
ответ будет: 
[{"user_id":159,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},{"user_id":160,"user_name":"Solomon Pein","user_profile_img":"5297c1c03b96866b.jpg"},{"user_id":161,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},{"user_id":176,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"}, .....
```

подскажите если можете как реализовать

Comment: А зачем тут лишняя нагрузка на базу и на сервер? Может, проще сразу получить нужные профили одним запросом к базе через `JOIN`? 
Ну или хотя бы прямо во втором запросе запросить только нужные `user_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[1]** Вариант, не требующий много знаний:

```js
var arr = [{"user_id": 160}, {"user_id": 240}];

var data = [
  {"user_id":159,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":160,"user_name":"Solomon Pein","user_profile_img":"5297c1c03b96866b.jpg"},
  {"user_id":161,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":176,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":240,"user_name":"bubu","user_profile_img":"Bubu"}
]

function filterByUserId(arr, data){
  var x = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
    for( var u = 0; u < data.length; u++ ){
      if( data[u].user_id === arr[i].user_id ){
        x.push( data[u] );
      } 
    }
  }
  return x;
}

console.log( filterByUserId(arr, data) );
```

**[2]** Пара методов массивов:

```js
var arr = [{"user_id": 160}, {"user_id": 240}];

var data = [
  {"user_id":159,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":160,"user_name":"Solomon Pein","user_profile_img":"5297c1c03b96866b.jpg"},
  {"user_id":161,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":176,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":240,"user_name":"bubu","user_profile_img":"Bubu"}
]

function filterByUserId(arr, data){
  // Собираю только числа user_id в отдельные массивы:
  var a = arr.map(function(e){ return e.user_id; });
  var d = data.map(function(e){ return e.user_id; });
  
  var x = [];
  a.forEach(function(e){ // или тоже map()
    // Один раз прохожу по первому массиву, достаю номер элемента, на котором он встречается
    // по этому же номеру добавляю в массив уже весь объект из data.
    x.push( data[ d.indexOf( e ) ] );
  });
  
  return x;
}

console.log( filterByUserId(arr, data) );
```

**[3]** Выпендреж максимально непонятным инопланетным JS:

```js
var arr = [{"user_id": 160}, {"user_id": 240}];

var data = [
  {"user_id":159,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":160,"user_name":"Solomon Pein","user_profile_img":"5297c1c03b96866b.jpg"},
  {"user_id":161,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":176,"user_name":null,"user_profile_img":"1"},
  {"user_id":240,"user_name":"bubu","user_profile_img":"Bubu"}
]

var filterByUserId = (arr, data) => arr.map(e => data[data.map(e => e.user_id).indexOf( e.user_id )]);

console.log( filterByUserId(arr, data) );
```

Comment: большое человеческое